# Do something if Enter is pressed and something else if End is typed. C++

Tags: c++

Today my question is the following: What do I have to this bit of code so it only keeps going if Enter is pressed and terminates if "End" is written.

If it is relevant in any way, the code itself is meant to write any word typed in backwards, just a word, not a sentence, it also works (at least for me), the only issue is truly implementing the Enter / End thingy.

By "it also works" I mean the function before inserting the "Enter or End" bits of code, thanks.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void trade(string p);

int main(){
    
    string word;
    string input;
    int q = 0;
    while(q == 0){
    cout << endl << "Write a word!" << endl;
    cin >> word;
    trade(word);
    
    cout << "Press Enter to continue and write a new word. Type End to terminate." << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if(input == ""){
       q = 0;
    } else if(input == "End") {
        q == 1;
    } else {
cout << "None of that follows the rules, we will end it for you either way. << endl;
q == 1;
}
    
    }
}


void trade(string p){
    
    string temp;
    temp = p;
    int sizee = p.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < sizee/2; i++){
        swap(p[i], p[sizee - 1 - i]);
    }
    if(p == temp){
    cout << "New Word: " << p << " is actually the same" << endl;
    } else{
        cout << "New Word: " << p << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please review your [mre]. It does not compile and hence fails to demonstrate what you want to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

Reading an `std::string str` with `cin >> str` reads a whitespace-separated, non-empty word. If you just press enter, that's just whitespace, so it keeps reading until you enter a word. Therefore, `str` can never be empty after that.

If you want to read until newline, use `getline(cin, str)` instead.